# Location and document path in nginx

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   d:/www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /js/api/ {
        root   D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

And the directory of the document is like this:

```
D:/workspace/javascript/maplib
    -- v1.0
         --main.js
    -- v1.1
```

Now I want to access the `v1.0/main.js` by `http://localhost/js/api/v1.0/main.js`.

And it returns a 404 error.

It seems that ngnix will tried to get the file through `D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/js/api/v1.0/main.js` which does not exist.

It seems that the string path in the `location`(in the url) must exist at the file system.

How to fix it to meet my requirement?

BTW, there is not only the js but also some other kinds of files like `.gif,.png,.html` inside the  `D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `alias`. Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

That is, replace

```
root   D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/;
```

by

```
alias   D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I had a similar issue and couldn't crack it for a while. Because of specific re-directions I couldn't just use "rewrite".
Alias helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `rewrite` inside `location /js/api/` for this, like:

```
rewrite ^/js/api(.*)$ $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use root with try_files, just add the try_files line

```
location /js/api/ {
    root   D:/workspace/javascript/maplib/;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```